# kubernetes v1.15.0 master is not able to reach pod ip address

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetes v1.15.0 master is not able to reach pod ip address. I have been able to get it working till 1.14 but this time its not working any more. I have been using and setting up k8s clustors in ec2 using kubeadm.

Please find a log below; Any comments.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-31 ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ip-172-31-16-120.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   97m    v1.15.0
ip-172-31-18-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    master   116m   v1.15.0
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-31 ~]$ kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE                                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
hello-deploy-7fd5fc7ff-dh9pw   1/1     Running   0          6m32s   10.44.0.3   ip-172-31-16-120.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
hello-deploy-7fd5fc7ff-vrxbd   1/1     Running   0          6m32s   10.44.0.4   ip-172-31-16-120.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
hello-pod1                     1/1     Running   0          22m     10.44.0.1   ip-172-31-16-120.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-31 ~]$ hostname
ip-172-31-18-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-31 ~]$ curl http://10.44.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply create service for your pod to access it within the cluster, type of service should be ClusterIP.

Although each Pod has a unique IP address, those IPs are not exposed outside the cluster without a Service. Services allow your applications to receive traffic. Services can be exposed in different ways by specifying a type in the ServiceSpec.

**ClusterIP** (default) - Exposes the Service on an internal IP in the cluster. This type makes the Service only reachable from within the cluste

Egg.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test
```

**Remember to match selector of service to pod's selector.**